# How to fill only first row after filtering

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to make an overview of different sub-tasks per project, think of three columns, `Project`, `Task-ID`, `Working hours`. After filtering for working hours, I would want to show all task-IDs that meet the requirement, but only show the Project in the first rows of respective tasks. Is there a way to solve this problem?

I've tried conditional formatting (changing the text color to meet the background if previous Project text cell is similar to current cell), but this does not change when filtering.

All data:

```
Project Sub-Task    Working hour
1       1-Collect   4
        1-Upload    3
        1-Read      6
2       2-Collect   3
        2-Upload    3
        2-Extract   5
3       3-Collect   6
        3-Upload    7
        3-Read      7
```

Goal (when filtered for `Working hour>5`):

```
Project Sub-Task    Working hour
1       1-Read      6
2       2-Extract   5
3       3-Collect   6
        3-Upload    7
        3-Read      7
```

Comment: Post sample data or share a sample workbook here.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "after filtering" or "when filtered by." Filtering can be done with built-in menu options or with functions like FILTER and QUERY. If you are wanting in-place filtering (which can only be done with the built-in menu filters), what you want to do is not possible. However, if you are open to the filtered results being placed elsewhere (e.g., somewhere to the right of the original data, in a separate "filter" sheet, etc.), then formulas can be devised.

Comment: In addition to what I said above, it would be most efficient for the volunteers here—and for you, as far as real-world application of any such formula suggestions to your real data—if you were to share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it), so that those here can see the actual data ranges involved, assess where the conditional number of hours and the output might best go, etc. If you do choose to share such a link, please make sure that the data in the spreadsheet accurately/realistically represents your *actual* data in form.

Comment: Are you still wanting the help of the forum on this issue? If the supplied solution does what you expect, please mark it as "Best Answer." This signifies that the issue is closed. If you've found another solution that works for you, please post it as an answer to your own post and mark that as "Best Answer." If you still need the help, please provide the additional information requested.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:C, C:C>5, A:A<>"")
```

Comment: From what I gather, the OP wants to have the Project number remain beside the topmost filtered-in sub-task (whatever that may happen to be based on the hours threshold), while your current formula will leave blanks for the Project number in the first column wherever that topmost filtered-in sub-task doesn't happen to align with the Project number. I have solutions in mind for that; but I'm waiting to find out more about the ACTUAL data, as it isn't clear to me whether the subs really have the Project number prefixed to them, etc. (BTW, I'm not the one who downvoted you.)

Comment: @ErikTyler exactly, the subs have the project number pre-fixed to them. Unfortunately I cannot upload the actual data due to confidentiality. But I would be glad if you could share your answer nevertheless :)

Comment: Thanks. @hunter-gatherers, Last time you checked in on this post was over 2.5 weeks ago. Whatever thoughts I might have had at the time and whatever preliminary problem solving I might have done are long gone. I suggest that you start a new post, sharing a link to a sheet containing A.) realistic but sanitized data and B.) the manually-entered results you want to see. That will not violate confidentiality any more than the data you posted in your original post. But it will allow people a jumping-off point on what is already an "old post" by now. Even a sheet with just your posted data...

Comment: @ErikTyler thanks for the input, I will do that in my future posts!